# MySQL selecting wrong index

Tags: mysql, indexing

The table in question has millions of records. The following query is really slow (takes up to four minutes to perform), because MySQL picks the primary key as index.

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM
    `activities`
WHERE
`integration_id` = 11
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 2
```

The table has multiple indexes, including an index on integration. When forced, the use of this index reduces the query time to about a second:

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM
    `activities`
USE INDEX (integration)
WHERE
`integration_id` = 11
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 2
```

Using EXPLAIN, MySQL shows the following:

**first query:** (the slow one)

- key: *PRIMARY*
- key_len: *4*
- rows: *5472*

**second query:** (the fast one)

- key: *integration*
- key_len: *5*
- rows: *24028*

Seeing MySQL's explanation, I understand why it picks the primary key. However, in reality the amount of rows in the first query should be millions; and indeed is excruciatingly slow to execute.

Unfortunately I cannot just force the index in the query, because the query is dynamic (some other clauses can be included), and an ORM is used. So i'm looking for a solution in MySQL's configuration, if possible.

**Extra info**

I found altering the query in some cases resulted in MySQL picking the correct index. E.g. removing the `ORDER BY` clause, and replacing `SELECT *` with `SELECT <insert every table column here>`. I've no clue why. Removing the order is no option for me, and manually selecting every column is tricky with the ORM (apart from that, I would like to know why this fixes the index picking).

**The EXPLAIN**

- id: '1'
- select_type: 'SIMPLE'
- table: 'activities'
- type: 'index'
- possible_keys: 'integration_category,integration_level,integration_category_level,integration'
- key: PRIMARY
- key_len: 4
- ref: null
- rows: '5473'
- Extra Using where

**SHOW CREATE TABLE**

```
'CREATE TABLE `activities` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `parameters` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `input` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `output` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `response` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `integration_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `integration_category` (`integration_id`,`category`),
  KEY `integration_level` (`integration_id`,`level`),
  KEY `integration_category_level` (`integration_id`,`category`,`level`),
  KEY `integration` (`integration_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `activities_integration_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`integration_id`) REFERENCES `integrations` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11262471 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci'
```

Comment: Add `id DESC` to your index...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto The question appears to be about MySQL, which AFAIK, silently ignores such parameters.

Comment: I've tried executing the query with `ORDER BY 'id' ASC`, to see if it would make any difference. It didn't.

Comment: Could you verify that `id` is your (single-column) primary key and that the index `integration` only consists of that one column? (Maybe add the `create table` for your table). Your 2nd query should not even take close to a second with correct indexes. And please add the complete explain output, especially the extra-part and information about partitions if you use them. You might also try an `optimize table activities` (although it should not have an effect here).

Comment: The table has 5 indexes in total: `id` (which is the single column primary key), `integration` (which is one column as well). This integration column is used in every query. Furthermore users can filter on two more columns, that's why three more indexes are used: `integration_level`, `integration_category` and `integration_category_level`. Since adding these indexes queries with these filters are very fast.

The EXPLAIN:   
`'1', 'SIMPLE', 'activities', 'index', 'integration_category,integration_level,integration_category_level,integration', 'PRIMARY', '4', NULL, '5473', 'Using where'`

Comment: I've updated the original post with the EXPLAIN for some readability.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it sounds like you have some redundant indexes that can be removed.

Comment: I've added `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to my post

Comment: First thing that pops to mind is to increase the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` so that selects can be done from RAM instead from disk. What happens when you perform the faster query with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE <rest of query here>`? Is it still fast?

Comment: Just checked, the fast query is still fast with the sql_no_cache. Interesting though, did not know about this option.

Comment: The innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to 134217728. Which is, if I read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589186/innodb-buffer-pool-size-variable-and-buffer-pool-size-in-innodb-status-mismatch, insufficient to say the least?

Comment: Yes, it's quite insufficient. Databases aren't slow because their code sucks, it's because hard drives are like snails and they have to read from those slow devices. If you want to make your system quick, you need to allocate sufficient resources (usually, for MySQL and other databases that means a lot of RAM). Use the mentioned variable to control how much of RAM is MySQL allowed to use to place its working data set inside, ideally this number would be equal or more to the actual size of your database. You should be seeing immediate performance improvements.

Comment: Thx, I will have to add more memory to the server in this case. However, it still strikes me as odd that in this case the primary key is used while the integration_id column should be used as index: every single query performed on this table uses this colum. It's like a user_id column, and users can of course only see their own records.